# GetType of int64 returning System.Nullable

Tags: .net, types, nullable

I've got an object that has a type property. When the type is set to Int64, and I try and pull the type info later, I get System.Nullable.

Here's the type Info

```
{Name = "Nullable`1" FullName = "System.Nullable`1[[System.Int64, mscorlib, Version=2.0.0.0]]"}
```

How do I get to the System.Int64 type of this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It sounds like you have a given type for which you want either that type or its underlying type if it is `Nullable<T>`.  The best way to do this would be something like this:

```
Nullable.GetUnderlyingType(yourObject.Type) ?? yourObject.Type;
```

Since `Nullabe.GetUnderlyingType` returns `null` if the given `Type` is not `Nullable<T>` you can use the null coalescing operator (??) to default the value to the original type.

Answer (score 1):

```
Type t = Nullable.GetUnderlyingType(nullableType);
```

See [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.nullable.getunderlyingtype.aspx).

Answer (score 1):

```
if ( property.PropertyType.IsGenericType 
  && property.PropertyType.GetGenericTypeDefinition() == typeof(Nullable<>) )
```

Answer (score 0):

If the object is not null, GetType will return Int64.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you set your type-property to "System.Int64?" anywhere? Otherwise I can not reproduce your behaviour.

Comment: Same for me... Strange behaviour that can certainly be explained by an information we don't have ;)